# Moving average with moving length

Tags: r, statistics, algorithmic-trading

How can I calculate a moving average (or other technical indicators) in R using different length parameters in different periods?

```
require(quantmod)
library(chron)
library(caTools)

## rm(list = ls())

#  Get the data
from.dat <- as.Date("2015-01-01")
#to.dat <- as.Date("2000-01-01")

ES <- getSymbols("^GSPC" , from = from.dat,auto.assign = FALSE) # to today

data <- ES
rm(ES)
data<-data[,6]
names(data)<-c("ES")


# create vectore with dummy values
data$num <- rep(10,length(data$ES))
for(i in 2:length(data$num)){
        if (data$num[i-1] == 10) {data$num[i] <- 5}
}


# moving average with moving length
data$sma<-SMA(data$ES, data$num )
plot(data$ema)
```

The plot does not show even a moving average. How to use technical indicators with moving length parameters?

Answer (score 1):

If i do understand you correcty you want data$sma to be a vector of alternating length-5 average and length-10 average.

```
l5sma <- SMA(data$ES, 5) 
l10sma <- SMA(data$ES, 10)

data$sma <- ifelse(data$num == 5, l5sma, l10sma)
plot(data$ES)
lines(data$sma, col = 3)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Floo0, but I was looking for some more general script.
What if I have a vector with much more "length" elements that change over the time?